# Получение данных в peewee

Tags: python, peewee

У меня есть такая конструкция:

```
try:
    turn_ip = TurnIp.get(TurnIp.turn == turn.id)
except TurnIp.DoesNotExist:
    turn_ip = None
```

Можно ли ее заменить чем-то вроде `get_or_None`, чтобы в случае неудачного поиска мне возращался `None`, а не ошибка ?

Answer (score 3):

Можно просто обернуть это в функцию:

```
def get_or_None(turn, TurnIp):
    try:
        turn_ip = TurnIp.get(TurnIp.turn == turn.id)
        return turn_ip     
    except TurnIp.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```